# Joomla 3.4: read more link has false url

Tags: joomla-3.x

I am working on a website with joomla 3.4.1. After a successfull upgrade from 2.5.28 I'm testing the site now.

Here I use a menu item for a category blog. But the read more button has a false url.
The url goes to **"http://examplesite.com/index.php/129-my-first-blog"** instead of going to **"http://examplesite.com/index.php/blogs/129-my-first-blog"**.

The problem is that the false url is going to the home site (home menu item) where I use a modul which has just be shown on the home site (home menu item). When I click on the read more button I'm going to see the modul which I don't want to see in this blog. 
I want that the read more button uses the blogs menu item instead of the home menu item.

Do you know what to do?

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution now. The home menu item has featured article instead of category blog. Now I can decide with that star symbol which blog is on the first site. And because both menu items haven't the same category, I can click on the read more buttons and get the correct link.

Comment: Yes, that is a good solution!

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an extra menuitem, a blog layout menuitem, linking to that category.
And name this menuitem **Blogs**

Comment: I allready have this and that's strange. The problem is that the first menu item has also the same category like the the second menu item. So if I click the read more button he is searching the menu item with the category and when it has found the first one which is the first menu item, it takes that one instead of the scond menu item. In the old joomla (2.5.28) it was no problem.